# Jquery validator code returning false all the time

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to get my head around this function. However everytime I run it, it tells the user the code is incorrect eventhough I have harded to true. Can someone suggest my flaw here

Html is simply

```
<form id="Join_league" method="post" action="<? echo $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <input name="league_code" id="league_code" class="input">
                    <br><br>
    <input id="Join_button" name="Join_button" value="Enter League" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This is my javascript/ ajax function

```
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery   validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
$.validator.addMethod("valid_code",function(value,element){
    var parameter="";
    $.ajax({
          url: "check_league_code.php",
          type: "POST",
          async: false,
          data: parameter,

          success:function(output)
                 {
                    return true;
                 }
     });
});


$("#Join_league").validate({
    rules: {
    league_code: {number : true,required : true ,
                              valid_code: true
                                            }
},
messages: {
    league_code: { required:"<strong>Please enter code</strong>",
                  number:"<strong>Please enter number only</strong>",
                valid_code:"<strong>Sorry incorrect code entered</strong>"
        }

}

   })

});

</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/urebug/4/watch

Comment: It's always `false` because you never hit your `success` callback, because there's apparently something wrong within your `ajax` code.  Otherwise, your jQuery Validation code is working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/vvqFB/1/

Comment: I have it updated and have it writing to the console in the success function whatever is passed back fron the php file. However when I hard code back true its not picking up the true value. Do I need to something else, updated code http://jsbin.com/urebug/4/edit

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use the jsBin... there isn't even any validation.

Comment: To more directly answer your question, as long as `success` is fired, you should get the `return true`.  I just don't think your `success` callback function is firing for whatever reason.  Your `data` is empty... what's supposed to happen when no data is passed into that php function?

Comment: Hi, Apologies I have updated the http://jsbin.com/urebug/5/edit .I have also included the php file under the css tab. Its not doing anything, except returning a value, trying to get the ajax working. It does return the value as it gets written out.

Comment: I got it working, by declaring a variable outside the ajax query and then assinging it a  value of true or false, depending on the value in the success function. I then return the variable outside the ajax query. Not sure if this is the best way, but it works

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i used to return true or false

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("valid_code", function(value,element) {
          var isSuccess = false;
          $.ajax({ url: "check_league_code.php",
          data: "",
          async: false,
          success: function(msg) { 
                      if(msg === "1")
                              {
                                isSuccess=true;
                              }
                    }
           });
                return isSuccess;
             },"<strong>Sorry incorrect code entered</strong>");



    $("#Join_league").validate({
        rules: {
            league_code: {
                required : true,
                number : true,
                valid_code: true
                        },
            messages: {
                league_code: {
                    required: "<strong>Please enter code</strong>",
                    number: "<strong>Please enter number only</strong>",
                    valid_code: "<strong>Sorry incorrect code entered</strong>"
                             }
                     }
        }
    });

});
```